# refresh token not responding

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I built the following authentication system with react and nodejs:
https://jwt-auth-client.vercel.app/
the back deploy on heroku and front on vercel
The problem is that the refresh token is not working.
Locally on my computer everything works fine
what could be the problem?

Comment: can you show your refresh token implementation

Comment: yes https://i.imagesup.co/images2/15fe5668340792541f8aac03fd4d6f28b14498f0.png

Comment: https://i.imagesup.co/images2/ddd870338f995c7736bb53b2f0d0d469888c03ee.png

Comment: Are you sending the tokens with cookies ?

Comment: True I send the token in cookies

Comment: since you are sending them as cookies please check if the cookie is actually set. If you are using Axios you need to set withCredentials to true for the backend to be able to set a cookie.

Comment: https://i.imagesup.co/images2/3028d5d7b7a99acd666c625c6ae7a4b0c3012a5b.png I am doing it. I mention again the exact same code works! Local.

Comment: Make sure the cookie domain is the vercel domain, in localhost it will work since both client and backend are on the same domain